# sh: python3: Operation not permitted (kubernetes)

Tags: linux, kubernetes

For a bit of context, I am following [this](https://www.kisphp.com/postgres/run-postgres11-and-pgadmin4-in-kubernetes-for-testing) tutorial on how to setup `pgadmin4` in kubernetes.

After attaching to my pod and running python, I am getting an error:

```sh
/pgadmin4 $ python3.8
sh: python3.8: Operation not permitted
/pgadmin4 $ ls -al /usr/bin/python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         14008 May  6 00:05 /usr/bin/python3
```

Not sure what is the reason nor how can I debug it. It's clearly not a permission denied issue. I suspect it might have to do with lack of linux capabilities but I am actually a bit clueless as how to go from here.

**Some additional information**:

- the command I am running is as follows:

```sh
$ kubectl run -ti --rm --overrides='
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "spec": {
    "containers":[{
        "name":"pgadmin",
        "image":"dpage/pgadmin4:latest",
        "command": ["sh"],
        "stdin": true,
        "tty": true,
        "resources": {
            "requests": {
                "cpu": 1,
                "memory": "1Gi"
            },
            "limits": {
                "cpu": "1",
                "memory": "1Gi"
            }
        },
        "envFrom": [{
            "secretRef": {
                "name": "proxy-secret"
            }
        }],
        "env": [{
            "name": "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL",
            "value": "user@domain.com"
        }, {
            "name": "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD",
            "value": "test"
        }]
    }],
    "securityContext": {
        "runAsUser": 5050,
        "runAsGroup": 5050
    }
    }
}' --image="dpage/pgadmin4:latest" -- bash
```

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using OpenShift by any chance? It does a lot of special magic with SELinux that might interfere with this kind of thing.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] and any relevant application code?  You also may find it easier to debug the system if you configure your application to write out text-format rather than PNG-format errors, and replacing the image in the question with the actual text of the error would help readers.

Comment: @coderanger I am not, even though I may have bumped into that OpenShift topic while searching for answers

Comment: @DavidMaze I knew I would get downvoted for that . I am finding troublesome adding more relevant information on this since I don't know where the issue resides. However I will try to add additional information

Comment: Check what the volume mount options inside the container look like? It's possible there something funky either with noexec mounts or xattrs? Both seem unlikely though as they would interfere with running stuff normally. Also the ls you show appears to be for `python3` instead of `python3.8`?

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is this:

https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/Dockerfile#L190

```
setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/bin/python3.8
```

Either allow NET_BIND_SERVICE for your pod, or build a custom container where you remove this capability from /usr/bin/python3.8.